# converting very large raw file to csv file, tf.data.Dataset

Tags: linux, csv, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a 200GB .raw file with tab as column separator (It has a tab before first column too). I want to convert this file to .csv file with comma as column separator. I used the following commands:

```
sed ‘s/\t/,/g’ File1.raw > File2.csv
```

However, when I want to read this csv file (File2.csv) with tf.data.Dataset (https://colab.research.google.com/github/adammichaelwood/tf-docs/blob/csv-feature-columns/site/en/r2/tutorials/load_data/csv.ipynb#scrollTo=sUtoed20cRJJ), then I get this error:

```
raise ValueError("Cannot have duplicate column names.")
ValueError: Cannot have duplicate column names.
```

I am sure my .raw file is fine. How can I convert File1.raw file to File2.csv file with comma as column separator without producing duplicated columns?

Comment: Paste the first line from each file into the body of your question. There is most likely a column name with a comma embedded or other formatting error. Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: @hsn15051 use this to remove duplication from last file, may be there is some wrong with tf tool,  the script for remove duplication  is: awk '!seen[$0]++'   File2.csv >  File2.csv.tmp &&  mv  File2.csv.tmp  File2.csv    (or any other scripts that remove common column names)